# How to prevent downloading the whole JSON file in angular ngx translate without changing the json file?

Tags: angular, bigdata, translation, multilingual, ngx-translate

I'm trying to translate my angular application to multiple languages using ngx translate.
Lately I just realized that the ngx translate service is downloading my JSON file which contains all of the translation keys and values with more than 5 mb size per each language.

Is there any way to prevent the downloading thing without changing the JSON file ?

What i need is something like this: client send the key or multiple keys to get the translations, ngx translate search those keys in the JSON file using language for the value of those keys (en.us for example) and then response to that translation request. With this solution I don't need to download the whole JSON file into client browser. I searched a lot and didn't find the right answer.

Here is my ng module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        },
        isolate:true
    }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: 5 MB is a lot of keys, you should consider moving resources to a local API

Comment: What you can actually do is to use lazy loaded modules, and you can also lazy load translations. You can split your huge 5 MB file into multiple files that will be downloaded whenever they are needed. You don't need 5 MB of translations to load the home page, most likely. You can also preload the lazy loaded modules, so that after your app shell loads, the rest of the modules will be also requested and available on the client-side.

Comment: the problem is we can not separate the keys that we need from that monster json files manually , now that we know it is not possible to prevent the downloading thing , is there any way to cull those keys which we need from using pipeline or something? or i should change my api which is creating those json files from sql server inside of ngxtranslate folder?

Answer (score 0):

ngx-translate works on the client-side, therefore it needs to be downloaded. ngx-translate can't do this on the server. I think your only option is to split your JSON in multiple files.

I am still wondering and impressed by the fact that one single language is 5mb!!! must be a monster of an application ;)

Comment: yes actuly 20 years old windows application and we are trying to transfer it to web application, the problem is we can not seprate the keys that we need from that monster json files now that i know it is not possible to prevent the downloading thing ,what is your suggestion