# how to translate our big angular application using ngx translate when our language file is so huge

Tags: angular, translate, ngx-translate

due to my last question in
[How to prevent downloading the whole JSON file in angular ngx translate without changing the json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73850000/how-to-prevent-downloading-the-whole-json-file-in-angular-ngx-translate-without)
we are trying to transfer our windows application into web application
in the windows application we use database for translation ,
`"select [translate] from [table] where [key] = 'translation key'"`
now that we are developing our web application using angular and we also need those translations , so we decide to use ngx translate service
in that case we add an api server which reads all the translations from database to create json files with translate key and value per each language like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            using (var x = new StreamWriter($"Angularpath\src\assets\i18n\{language}.json"))
            {
                x.Write(json);
            }
```

the problem is the json files that api is creating from db are so huge and we can not just decouple the web application translation from our last windows application because it is still working and we have to keep supporting it,
some of our friends suggest to make those json files separate which needs so much time wasted and loss,
if there is any solution to prevent this issues i will be glad,
tnx <3

Comment: If the file is so huge, then yes, splitting it is the solution.

Comment: File based, i.e. with many files, is not ideal. You could use browser side decompression with server-side compressing ***.json.gz**. You would still need to deliver a plain .json in some cases - for instance to your Windows application. And the benefits are not great.

Comment: I would build a small CLI tool that reads all the translation keys from the DB and generates multiple, smaller JSON files for the web client. You don't need the whole 5 MB file in your angular project, you can have multiple smaller files and lazy load them whenever you need. The CLI tool is there for your convenience, in case some of the translations from the DB get updated, deleted, created, etc. You just run that, you shove the newly generated JSON files into the angular project and you're good to go.